# Error java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed when running application on Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

Hello I found this exception when I run my application on Android kitkat 4.4

```
11-28 08:50:00.752: E/dalvikvm(10056): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.vis.kotob-2/libdatabase_sqlcipher.so") 
failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android10MemoryBaseC1ERKNS_2spINS_11IMemoryHeapEEElj" 
referenced by "libdatabase_sqlcipher.so"...



11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056): Process: com.his.mojak, PID: 10056
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN7android10MemoryBaseC1ERKNS_2spINS_11IMemoryHeapEEElj" referenced by "libdatabase_sqlcipher.so"...
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:143)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(SQLiteDatabase.java:136)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at com.his.mojak.model.db.DBManager.<init>(DBManager.java:24)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at com.his.mojak.model.db.DBManager.getInstance(DBManager.java:15)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at com.his.mojak.model.dao.db.DbAbstractDao.<init>(DbAbstractDao.java:13)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at com.his.mojak.model.dao.db.UserDataDao.<init>(UserDataDao.java:10)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at com.his.mojak.model.dao.db.UserDataDao.getInstance(UserDataDao.java:19)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at com.his.mojak.ui.activity.splash.SplashController.sessionExpired(SplashController.java:157)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at com.his.mojak.ui.activity.splash.SplashActivity.onSplashFinished(SplashActivity.java:55)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at com.his.mojak.ui.activity.splash.SplashController$1.handleMessage(SplashController.java:72)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-28 08:50:00.762: E/AndroidRuntime(10056):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's your sqlcipher version?

There is an issue with older(v2.2.0) versions for KitKat: https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/issues/107

Get the latest release of the binaries (e.g. http://sqlcipher.net/downloads or directly [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/sqlcipher/SQLCipher+for+Android+v3.0.1.zip)) or compile the latest source, and you should be fine!